# How to prevent dom changes from resetting on ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am building a web application with Django.
I have already implemented an API with the rest framework.

This is the code im using to connect to my API:

```
$(document).ready()

            $.ajax ({
                url: "http://localhost:8000/main_api/Waffel",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(res) {
                        document.getElementById("Einzelne1").innerHTML = res[0].anzahl;
                        document.getElementById("Einzelne2").innerHTML = res[1].anzahl;
                        document.getElementById("Einzelne3").innerHTML = res[2].anzahl;
                        document.getElementById("Einzelne4").innerHTML = res[3].anzahl;
                        console.log(res)                    
                }
            });
```

Sadly this doesn't change anything on my main site, the only thing that is executed is `console.log(res)`.

One interesting thing is, that when I add this at the end of the file and reload the page, the modified innerHTML actually shows up before it gets changed back the second the ajax request finishes.

```
document.getElementById("Einzelne2").innerHTML = res[1].anzahl;
document.getElementById("Einzelne3").innerHTML = res[2].anzahl;
document.getElementById("Einzelne4").innerHTML = res[3].anzahl;
```

What could be done to prevent this?
And if fixing that is impossible, what other ways could be there to load data from the API and then display it in the HTML page.

EDIT:

```
[{"id":3,"name":"Schokolade","anzahl":1},{"id":4,"name":"Zucker","anzahl":2},{"id":5,"name":"Zimt und Zucker","anzahl":3},{"id":6,"name":"Blauberre","anzahl":4}]
```

Comment: Can you write what is in the "res"? Is it JSON encoded string? Did you tried to parseJSON?

Comment: res is the result Data Ajax Returns and no but I have tried getJSON and that did result in the exact same thing

Comment: But i suppose it is in JSON formated string, can you paste what console.log(res)  
 shows?

Comment: @Trueman `dataType:'json'` will cause it to be parsed already. With that said showing what `res` looks like will definitely help

Comment: @Truemann it Outputs a normal json Format

Comment: I will stick to "what res looks like will definitely help" :)

Comment: The code above looks fine, so we need to *see* the response.  Please post it, rather than describe it.

Comment: @Archer okay, i did

Comment: That's not the format it comes from the API.  Please post the *actual response*

Comment: @Archer okay sorry, but thats the format you were talking about right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code above is exactly as you have it in your page then you've implemented the `$(document).ready()` handler incorrectly.  You need to put the code inside a function and add it as a parameter, like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax ({
        url: "http://localhost:8000/main_api/Waffel",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res) {
            document.getElementById("Einzelne1").innerHTML = res[0].anzahl;
            document.getElementById("Einzelne2").innerHTML = res[1].anzahl;
            document.getElementById("Einzelne3").innerHTML = res[2].anzahl;
            document.getElementById("Einzelne4").innerHTML = res[3].anzahl;
            console.log(res)                    
        }
    });
});
```

Because you implemented it incorrectly the ready handler was doing nothing and your ajax call was being executed before the page was actually loaded.  You would probably have never noticed it had you deployed it to a live environment, but running it on localhost would mean it runs quick enough for the ajax call to be completed instantly.